# How to configure Jenkins to not copy artifacts through the master for the same slave?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I use [Copy Artifacts Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Copy+Artifact+Plugin) to copy artifacts between two related jobs. However, it seems that even if two jobs are executed on the same slave (and in my case, it always be the case b/c slaves represent different platforms), artifacts will be copied over the network (through the master I suppose) which slows down downstream job significantly when artifacts are large or have a lot of files.

Is there a way to configure Jenkins to check for local copies (on the slave) of the artifacts before copying them over the network?